# How to redirect an asp page to 2 other pages?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, crystal-reports

I have a web page with checkbox list to choose multiple crystal reports to view. I want to open these reports in new tabs or windows.
I tried this :

This is the show report button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Show Report" OnClick="ButtonShowReport_Click"
                        CssClass="button" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"/>
```

And this is my gridview control:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
       RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       DataKeyNames="AccountID">
       <RowStyle BackColor="#>
       <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choose Client's Accounts">
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label id="lblAccountId" runat ="server" text='<%# Eval("AccountID")%>'>
                    </asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountID" HeaderText="AccountID" Visible="false"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountName" HeaderText="Account Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Client Name" />
       </Columns>
       <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

My c# code looks like:

```
protected void ButtonShowReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string accountID;
        int Rows = GridView1.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        {
            //CheckBoxField cb = ((CheckBoxField)gvASH.Rows[i].Cells[1]).;
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (cb.Checked == true)
            {
                accountID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblAccountID")).Text;//GridView1.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString();//GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                //Button2.Enabled = true;
                openReport(accountID);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void openReport(string accountID)
    {
        //some code for setting parameters of the crystal report
        //and for creating report key

        Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Report.aspx?ReportKey={0}", 
            ReportKey.ToString()),false);
    }
```

So if the user checked 2 reports and clicked on the ShowReport button, it'll do the loop but opens only one new tab with the last report chosen ...

Any Suggestions please ??

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the control which triggers the redirect.  I know this works for Buttons/LinkButtons, not sure if it will work on a checkbox though.

```
OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"
```

Comment: thanks for replying ...
Actually I added it and it opens the crystal report correctly in a new tab. the problem is that only the last checked report opens in that page, while I need that more than one report open at the same time in more than one tab

Answer (score 0):

One method you might consider:

Instead of doing the Redirect to each report inside the code behind - dynamically generate some JavaScript that has uses window.open for each report.  The javascript would look similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open("<report1URL>", "_blank");
window.open("<report2URL>", "_blank");
...
window.open("<reportNURL>", "_blank");
</script>
```

Then, instead of doing a Response.Redirect, you should be able to do a Respone.Write() to get the browser to execute the code.

```
string myJavaScript= <dynamicallyGenerateJavascript>;
Response.Write(myJavaScript);
```